# How to move elements from payment to shipment in checkout - magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to move elements from payment to shipment in checkout - magento 2
As you see in the screenshot I need to move the squared part from payment page to shipment and also I need to move some parts from shipment to payment.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **shipping-step** and **payment-step** comes from **checkout_index_index.xml**
So, if you want to move the component like the above section named as **custom-field** which may be in shipping-step or billing-step, so swap it accordingly as your wish.
For example, take a look at the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">module_name/js/view/custom-text</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

In, this **module_name/js/view/custom-text** is an custom text which render from the custom module and which goes under shipping-step. 
Use sorting to display wherever you wish to see your component.
`<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>`
Hope it will help somehow. Let me know if you need any clarifications.